# LiFePO4 battery charger and inverter in parallel

Tags: inverter, charger, bms, lifepo4

I've got a  brand new LiFePO4 battery (200 Ah) with internal BMS, got the Blue Smart IP65 Charger from Victron Energy and an inverter.
The easiest way to connect them is in parallel (off course adding fuses, switches etc.), but a question arise: what happens in case the battery is disconnected (for example because of the internal BMS) and the charger is active?
The inverter has a big capacitor which receives a constant current from the charger. **I'm expecting an explosion of the capacitors.**
How this situation should be managed? The circuit is meant to be used on a RV, how can I prevent the charger to continuously charge the inverter's capacitors? The BMS is internal to the battery and there is no way to see/know if it disconnected the battery.

Thanks

Comment: As others have said: the charger will never go above the maximum voltage set for LiFePO4 batteries. There will be no explosion. If the inverter was active at the time the battery disconnected, the charger will either provide current to the inverter (for as long as the charger's maximum load is not exceeded), or shut down.

Answer (score 0):

Victron's datasheets not only state plausible upper limits on voltage:
They explicitly claim a *power supply mode*.

From their [Blue Smart IP65 Charger manual](https://www.victronenergy.com/media/pg/Blue_Smart_IP65_Charger_manual_230V/en/advanced-configuration.html#UUID-3cbe9344-2f18-5b47-a876-fab0d4789544), section *7.3 Advanced Configuration: Power supply function*:

> While it’s still possible to use the charger as a power supply without changing any settings, a dedicated ‘Power supply’ mode exists for this purpose/usage.
>
> If the charger will be used as a power supply, it is recommended to activate ‘Power supply’ mode, as it will disable the internal charge logic and provide a constant DC supply voltage.

Comment: COuld you please elaborate better this answer ? The charger must be working in charging mde...not as power supplier

Comment: I do understand that. The point is that there are a lot of reasons why I cannot do it, for example the main fuse (between the battery and the charger) may blow .. I cannot watch it continuously and switch the mode in few seconds...

Comment: Whether or not you can/would *activate ‘Power supply’ mode*: **Why** would the fuse blow? Charger output current is limited; I expect inverter input current to be limited, too.

Comment: take a look here [link] (https://www.victronenergy.it/upload/documents/VE-direct-drawing-with-Phoenix-charger-12-50-1-inverter-375W-MPPT-100-30.pdf). The "pre main" fuse may blow but at the same moment some of the others may not, in this case the chargers are connected to the inverter... I this it is rare but still possible.

Comment: I *don't get* your concerns: while you don't state your inverter is from Victron, too, and the diagram shows a charger from a different family, I'd take it as a (non-strong) hint such a configuration is viable. Few words before my above quote: *it’s still possible to use the [Blue Smart] charger as a power supply without changing any settings*.

Answer (score 0):

The inverter should be just fine, as it will limit its current draw to match the output requirements.  It has to be this way, as the battery can source hundreds for amps, which would itself be an issue if The inverter didn't control its power input.

As noted above, the Victoron unit also has a PSU mode which disables the normal charge cycle for batteries. Use this if you don't have a battery in circuit.

Comment: Damned autocorrect! Typo fixed. :-)

Comment: My question is: what happens to a capacitor in case it is connected to a constant current source ? even just few milliamps? The voltage grows .. till it reaches its maximum .. and the capacitor explodes, isn't it ? Inverters do have big capacitors inside on the DC side.

Comment: just forgot to mention again: we cannot charge a LiFePO4 battery with a simple DC generator....I cannot use it as such

Comment: Constant current mode sets the _maximum_ current irrespective of what the load tries to draw.  However, if the load tries to draw less, then that is the current which will be drawn. The PSU doesn't try and "force" current into the load device.